# p5.js went blank when I tried to run my code

Tags: javascript, web, p5.js

I'm trying to embed 2 p5 code on the same page, so I modified my original p5 code to give an id to the canvas. However, when I tried to run the code, the whole p5 online editor page went blank.

The code runs well before I added the id. Can anyone let me know what the issue is?

I added an id for the canvas and include the id name on html.

```js
var s1 = function(f) {
  var particles2 = [];
  var viscosity2;
  var c2;
  var canvas;

  f.setup = function() {
    canvas = f.createCanvas(f.windowWidth, f.windowHeight);
    f.frameRate(60);
    f.noStroke();

    c2 = f.color(13, 104, 167);
    viscosity2 = 0.8;

    // increase the density of particles
    for (var i = 0; i < 900; i++) {
      particles2.push(new Particle2(f.random(f.width / 8, f.width / 4), f.random(f.height - f.height / 18, f.height + f.height / 15), c2));
    }
  };

  f.keyPressed = function() {
    if (f.key === ' ') {
      f.noLoop();
    }
    if (f.key === 's') {
      f.save();
    }
  };

  f.draw = function() {
    f.background(0);

    // makes the particles attract/repel each other
    f.handleFooterInteractions();

    // moves each particle, then draws it
    for (var i = 0; i < f.particles2.length; i++) {
      f.particles2[i].move();
      f.particles2[i].display();
    }
  };

  f.Particle2 = function(x, y, c)  {
    this.xPos = x;
    this.yPos = y;
    this.xVel = 0;
    this.yVel = 0;

    //particle size
    this.mass = f.random(0.005, 0.02);
    this.colour = c;

    // moves the particle
    this.move = function() {
      this.xPos += this.xVel;
      this.yPos += this.yVel;
    };

    // displays the particle
    this.display = function() {
      f.fill(this.colour);
      f.ellipse(this.xPos, this.yPos, this.mass * 1000, this.mass * 1000);
    };
  }

  f.handleFooterInteractions = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < f.particles2.length; i++) {
      var accX = 0;
      var accY = 0;

      // particle interaction
      for (var j = 0; j < f.particles2.length; j++) {
        if (i !== j) {
          var x = f.particles2[j].xPos - f.particles2[i].xPos;
          var y = f.particles2[j].yPos - f.particles2[i].yPos;
          var dis = f.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
          if (dis < 1) dis = 1;

          //adjust circle size
          var force = (dis - 600) * f.particles2[j].mass / dis;
          accX += force * x;
          accY += force * y;
        }

        // mouse interaction
        var x = mouseX - f.particles2[i].xPos;
        var y = mouseY - f.particles2[i].yPos;
        var dis = f.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

        // adds a dampening effect
        if (dis < 40) dis = 40;
        if (dis > 50) dis = 50;

        var force = (dis - 50) / (5 * dis);
        accX += force * x;
        accY += force * y;
      }
      f.particles2[i].xVel = f.particles2[i].xVel * viscosity2 + accX * f.particles2[i].mass;
      f.particles2[i].yVel = f.particles2[i].yVel * viscosity2 + accY * f.particles2[i].mass;
    }
  }

};

var myp5 = new p5(s1, 'footer');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the one hand there are way too many `f.` in your code, on the other hand some are missing. You must distinguish between the functions, properties, and classes populated by `p5`, which must be addressed by `f.`, and your own functions, properties, and classes, which have their own scope:

```js
var s1 = function(f) {
  var particles2 = [];
  var viscosity2;
  var c2;
  var canvas;

  f.setup = function() {
    canvas = f.createCanvas(f.windowWidth, f.windowHeight);
    f.frameRate(60);
    f.noStroke();

    c2 = f.color(13, 104, 167);
    viscosity2 = 0.8;

    // increase the density of particles
    for (var i = 0; i < 900; i++) {
      particles2.push(new Particle2(f.random(f.width / 8, f.width / 4), f.random(f.height - f.height / 18, f.height + f.height / 15), c2));
    }
  };

  f.keyPressed = function() {
    if (f.key === ' ') {
      f.noLoop();
    }
    if (f.key === 's') {
      f.save();
    }
  };

  f.draw = function() {
    f.background(0);

    // makes the particles attract/repel each other
    handleFooterInteractions();

    // moves each particle, then draws it
    for (var i = 0; i < particles2.length; i++) {
      particles2[i].move();
      particles2[i].display();
    }
  };

  Particle2 = function(x, y, c)  {
    this.xPos = x;
    this.yPos = y;
    this.xVel = 0;
    this.yVel = 0;

    //particle size
    this.mass = f.random(0.005, 0.02);
    this.colour = c;

    // moves the particle
    this.move = function() {
      this.xPos += this.xVel;
      this.yPos += this.yVel;
    };

    // displays the particle
    this.display = function() {
      f.fill(this.colour);
      f.ellipse(this.xPos, this.yPos, this.mass * 1000, this.mass * 1000);
    };
  }

  handleFooterInteractions = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < particles2.length; i++) {
      var accX = 0;
      var accY = 0;

      // particle interaction
      for (var j = 0; j < particles2.length; j++) {
        if (i !== j) {
          var x = particles2[j].xPos - particles2[i].xPos;
          var y = particles2[j].yPos - particles2[i].yPos;
          var dis = f.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
          if (dis < 1) dis = 1;

          //adjust circle size
          var force = (dis - 600) * particles2[j].mass / dis;
          accX += force * x;
          accY += force * y;
        }

        // mouse interaction
        var x = f.mouseX - particles2[i].xPos;
        var y = f.mouseY - particles2[i].yPos;
        var dis = f.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

        // adds a dampening effect
        if (dis < 40) dis = 40;
        if (dis > 50) dis = 50;

        var force = (dis - 50) / (5 * dis);
        accX += force * x;
        accY += force * y;
      }
      particles2[i].xVel = particles2[i].xVel * viscosity2 + accX * particles2[i].mass;
      particles2[i].yVel = particles2[i].yVel * viscosity2 + accY * particles2[i].mass;
    }
  }

};

var myp5 = new p5(s1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.7.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```